# DreamWeaver Right Code Margin

Tags: dreamweaver, text-formatting

It's futile trying to search for this on Google, as all I get are new programmers' questions about CSS `margin-right`.

**Is it possible to have a right code margin line appear in DreamWeaver**, so I know when to wrap my comments, etc.?

I'm used to having this in NetBeans, Notepad++, Gedit, and other free editors, so I figured a high-priced product like DreamWeaver would have this, too, but I can't find it in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a look through the Edit > preferences in DW CS6 and nothing to help with EOL margin lines for a visual cue as your per your request.

I have taken a look through the Adobe Dreamweaver Exchange for some kind of extension which could aid in this task but no luck.

Nothing found in the View > Guides or in View > Visual Aids which would work in code view. only suggestion I have is to use Sublime or any of the mentioned editors in your post to do external coding then for WYSIWYG work bring it back into DW.

I feel your problem as Photoshop you can have layout guides for visual stuff so why does Adobe not port it over into DW, maybe a feature request for DW CS7 :)

Comment: Wow... it's things like this that keep me from considering it a useful editor

Comment: Any updates to this answer from the new version?